# Separate navbar Ctrl for one-page application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building a one page application with AngularJS. Right now I am using just one controller which is one very long file (of course there are several factories but nevertheless the Ctrl is still full). So as I could divide my page into navbar and the body, i thought of having a separate Ctrl for the navbar. (the thing is here, the navbar includes a big options dropdown and some other stuff, so not just Title and Links) However I do not really how to do that. Right now my main.html file looks like the following:

```
<div ng-include="'views/templates/navbar.html'" id="navbarContainer"></div>

<div id="map-container" class="container-fluid">
  <leaflet id="map" lf-center="hamburg" markers-nested="true" layers="layers" defaults="defaults" markers="markers" class="map"></leaflet>
</div>
```

So as you can see, my navbar is a template in the main html file. Additionally the navbar and the main html should have the same route. So now, I definitely do not know how to use a second Ctrl. Do I not use the ng-template or can I just give the ng-template a separate Ctrl than the part below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `navbar.html` file can include its own controller.

**Navbar.html**

```
<div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
  <!-- your code -->
</div>
```

See the [Controller: Scope Inheritance Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) in the AngularJS Docs for more info.

Comment: even though it is included with ng-temaple and therefore inherited the controller of the main file it is in?

Comment: @threxx yes. angular `scopes` come into play for that (inheritance)